# keyboard hides text boxes in static table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, textbox, keyboard, settings

Object C - iOS development. Hello all. I have a static table view with several text boxes to enter information. When I tap on a lower box, the keyboard hides the text box preventing entry of text. This app uses another static table view controller and when a lower text box is tapped, the view scrolls up allowing text to be entered, so it works fine. I must be missing a setting of some sort, but can't find it. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you check to see how the other one works?

Comment: I've compare all setting on the controller and their all the same. This app has a total of four controller in the same configuration and all but this one works as expected. There must be something I'm missing. I would hate to have to rebuild the controller.

Comment: Any usage of UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is the project ?

Comment: No, I have not used that method.

Comment: Interesting. I've isolated where the problem is coming from. When I add the custom class file, it starts misbehaving. So it's not in a any view setting.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a full screen table view controller by a subclass of `UITableViewController` then the keyboard interaction will be handled for you.

If you don't (you aren't using `UITableViewController`) then you need to do it yourself. Basically, you need to observe the keyboard notifications and use the keyboard frame they provide to you to change the table view frame so that it isn't below the keyboard.

See the docs for `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html). You might also like [this project](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding).

Comment: I am subclassing UITableViewController for my controller class. It's working perfectly for the other controller. Just this one is being a pain.

Comment: And the table view occupies the whole screen ?

Comment: Yes. Table view consist of three cell each having text boxes. Very similar to several other controller I've subclassed and that are working great. When I tap on a lower cell the keyboard covers the text box and I can't even scroll up to view the text box on this one. Very strange.

Comment: I have a similar problem, my tableview doesn't occupy the whole screen, does this mean I should do the logic myself? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143745/uitableview-with-large-static-cells-doesnt-scroll-to-where-it-should