# UITableView with large static cells doesn't scroll to where it should

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, interface-builder

So I have a unique iOS project (read as clients accepted a design before I started working here and the design contains checkboxes, dropdowns, tabular data (rows+columns,etc.) which requires a long tableview which contains 3 sections, the sections themselves vary from 50-700pt.

It appears this wasn't something Apple took into account as the table view does not scroll properly to all cells, specifically, when the keyboard is not yet open and I click on a textfield at the bottom of a long section it scrolls to entirely the wrong section.

I'm curious if there is something obvious I'm missing, I've tried using the library [TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) to no avail, it sounds very promising but also doesn't handle my situation.

I'd prefer to stick with a table view instead of a scrollview as I've already built out and handled headers, certain events, etc.

ALSO, after reading other posts it may be pertinent that I'm in landscape mode only on iPads and this tableview + controller is inside a container controller so it's size is fixed at 984x543

Comment: Why not scroll your text field into visible? A table view is a scrollview, so you could calculate the content offset and scroll after keyboard apperas.

Comment: This is something I've done before and a definite possibility, I just wanted to see if it was something else others have run into and if there is a solution as tableviews are scrollviews and should handle this auto-magically :)

Comment: What constitutes "entirely the wrong section"? Is the row visible after the scroll?

Comment: Yes Wain, technically the bottom of the row (very very tall row) is visible.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce the issue where the table view does not scroll properly to text fields in static cells that are large. I just filed a bug report. Funny how I ran into this four years later.

Comment: Good ol' Stack Overflow eh @MichaelMcKenna :) I don't recall if I filed a radar with Apple back in the day but I may as well again.